# scoring argument in scikit-learn LassoCV, LassoLarsCV, ElasticNetCV

Tags: regression, scikit-learn

I was looking at the arguments in the linear regularization methods with cross validation within scikit-learn. RidgeCV has an argument scoring which is None by default but one can use a custom scorer (e.g. RMSE). I noticed that no such option is given for the rest of the classes (LassoCV, LassoLarsCV, ElasticNetCV). Why is this? Is MSE used by default in all of them?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`RidgeCV` implements CV by `GridSearchCV`, which supports custom scorer.

However, `LassoCV` and `ElasticNetCV` implement CV by `LinearModelCV`, with MSE as scoring hard-coded. `LassoLarsCV` impletments CV by `LarsCV`, with MSE as scoring hard-coded too.

If you want to use other scorers, maybe you can use `GridSearchCV` directly.

### References

https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/14031f6/sklearn/linear_model/ridge.py#L1092

https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/14031f6/sklearn/linear_model/coordinate_descent.py#L1181

https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/14031f6/sklearn/linear_model/least_angle.py#L1143